# Any way to align multiple lines of text in lua using string.format()?

Tags: string, lua, alignment, string.format, monospace

So I'm using a monospace font and in the debug window when I print multiple lines of my text string all the columns line up nicely.

But when I output that same string, using the same font inside of a 3rd party game engine all the vertical alignment is off.

I know we can't address the engine here, but are there any commands I for string.format() that I can use like 'tabs' or something to line up columns instead of 'spaces' as it's the spaces that are causing the problem in the engine.

Comment: Why would spaces cause problems? Tabs are more likely to cause problems since the tab stops and tab widths are variable; spaces will always take exactly one space in a monospace font (duh). Also please provide a snippet and more details.

Comment: Why cant we "address the engine here"? what engine it is is usually a very important detail.